# String value not showing in output.setText

Tags: java, android

Im trying to show the day name along with the date in my app and the text defined as "**text**" shows up fine and integer values also show up fine, but it will not show a text variable, this is what I have:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TextView output3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output3);

int dayno = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String dayName = new String();// also tried String dayName = ""; with the same results
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Sun";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Mon";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Tue";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Wed";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Thu";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Fri";
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Sat";
```

also tried it like this:

```
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Sun";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Mon";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Tue";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Wed";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Thu";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Fri";}
if (dayno == 1) {dayName = "Sat";}

output3.setText(hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " Week " + weekno + ", " + dayName + ", " + yearno);
```

this is the result I am getting (middle text field has the error)
[image]

I can't figure out what could be wrong here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: The lesson here is to not write all your code on a single incoherent line so you can more easily see the cause of failure (the question has been edited by another member of SO to be made coherent).

Comment: Now that I've edited your code so that it is readable, just look at those if-statements. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: You can replace all that with this: `String dayName = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE").format(new Date());`.

Comment: Yes sorry guys it was a copy paste error in my code, ive been working on this app for the last 12 hours (not that problem tho lol) and thanks for the sugestions everyone, the simpleDateFormat appears to be a lot easier. Oh, and I have a bad habit of 'single line incoherent coding' once my classes get over a thousand lines long, and that is exactly what gets me in trouble when errors occur because it is difficult to catch simple errors like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code as follows:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
TextView output3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output3);

int dayno = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String dayName = new String();// also tried String dayName = ""; with the same results
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Sun";
if (dayno == 2) dayName = "Mon";
if (dayno == 3) dayName = "Tue";
if (dayno == 4) dayName = "Wed";
if (dayno == 5) dayName = "Thu";
if (dayno == 6) dayName = "Fri";
if (dayno == 7) dayName = "Sat";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your days number are same in if condition. Write your condition properly.Use `Switch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

All your if clauses check if `dayno` is `1`. Change them to the right values or use a switch statement and it should work fine. A switch statement for that would look like this:

```
switch(dayno) {
    case Calendar.SUNDAY: 
        dayName = "Sun"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.MONDAY: 
        dayName = "Mon"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.TUESDAY: 
        dayName = "Tue"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.WEDNESDAY: 
        dayName = "Wed"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.THURSDAY: 
        dayName = "Thu"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.FRIDAY:
        dayName = "Fri"; 
        break;
    case Calendar.SATURDAY:
        dayName = "Sat"; 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by the way use the class [DateFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html) and with this avoid to re invent the wheel

## Example:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

int dayno = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String[] weekdays = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays();
System.out.println(weekdays[dayno]);
```

, but lets go back to your question

You have this in the code

```
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Sun";
 
if (dayno == 1) dayName = "Mon";
```

but what if dayno is not  1??
then  **dayName** is empty... you have a copy/paste error

You meant for sure:

```
if (dayno == 1) {
    dayName = "Sun"
} else if (dayno == 2) {
    dayName = "Mon";
}...
```

etc etc

Answer (score 0):

@Leon is right. You want something like this:

```
int dayno = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String dayName = new String();

switch(dayno) {
    case 1: dayName = "Sun"; break;
    case 2: dayName = "Mon"; break;
    case 3: dayName = "Tue"; break;
    case 4: dayName = "Wed"; break;
    case 5: dayName = "Thu"; break;
    case 6: dayName = "Fri"; break;
    case 7: dayName = "Sat"; break;
    default: dayName = "dayno is not [1, 7]"; break;
}
```

*Assuming Sunday is 1...*

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a switch or many if statements, print your time appropriately using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(); 
// Or... df = new SimpleDateFormat("SOME-TIME-FORMAT");
String nowSting = df.format(now.getTime());
textView.setText(nowString);
```

I believe your format is something like this

```
hh:mm:ss Week w, EEE, yyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SWITCH to perform this.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
String dayName;
TextView output3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output3);

int dayno = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

switch(dayno){
  case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
  case 2: dayName = "Monday"; break;
  case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
  case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
  case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
  case 6: dayName = "Friday"; break;
  case 7: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
}
```